# PHP mySQL query remove double array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

In the example below I am taking an array of the ID's only to turn it into a while and then back into an array only to explode it on the comma on the page. Surely there must be an easier way of doing this.

I am after an array of the $row['ID']s

```
function get_other_elector_phone($telephone,$current,$criteria){
    $the_others = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM electors WHERE telephone = '$telephone' $criteria"); $results = '';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($the_others))  { 
    $results .= $row['ID'].','; } return $results;
}


$others = get_other_elector_phone(g('electors',$elector,'telephone'),$elector,$criteria); 
                    if($others){ $others = explode(',',$others);
```

Comment: Just... build and return an array instead of a string?

Answer (score 0):

just as @daverandom said, just rebuild an array, this is the syntax :

```
function get_other_elector_phone($telephone,$current,$criteria){
  $the_others=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM electors WHERE telephone = '$telephone' $criteria"); 
  $results = array();
  $i=0;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($the_others))  { 
    $results [$i]= $row['ID'];
    $i++; 
  } 
  //results returned outside loop
  return $results;
}

$others = get_other_elector_phone(g('electors',$elector,'telephone'),$elector,$criteria);
```

The $others will return an array.

Comment: That is only returning the first result nor all of them as mine did

Comment: In this example, `return $results` needs to be outside of the `while` loop. You can also dispense with `$i`; assigning `$results[] = $row['ID']` will do the same.

Comment: thank @joe bowman, I mean like that, I just placed the wrong place

Answer (score -1):

instead of

```
function get_other_elector_phone($telephone,$current,$criteria){
  $the_others = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM electors WHERE telephone = '$telephone' $criteria"); $results = '';
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($the_others))  { 
    $results .= $row['ID'].','; } return $results;
  }
}
```

just return the result of `mysql_fetch_array()`

```
function get_other_elector_phone($telephone,$current,$criteria){
  $the_others = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM electors WHERE telephone = '$telephone' $criteria"); $results = '';
  return mysql_fetch_array($the_others);
}
```

then there is no need to explode the output of the function.

Comment: Something's wrong as its getting results for a lot more than just the ID column

Comment: use `SELECT ID ...` rather than `SELECT * ...` if you just want the ID column.